# Is there a shortcode for linking to a user profile in an answer?

Tags: feature-request, support

Sometimes I want to refer to a specific user in an answer.

Something along the lines of

> "From the answers of UserA and UserB I have crafted this super useful solution..."

Is there a shortcode creating a link to a user profile using the user name? Similar to the @ we have in the comments, but in an answer.

Comment: Personally I just link directly to the answers with the name as the link text

Comment: I do the same as Ben. If you're referring to the answer rather than the user, linking to the answer makes more sense. The answer will have a link to the user. Additionally, I find it unlikely that the content of their user page will be relevant enough to your answer that you want to link to it.

Comment: I completely agree with both of you. Linking to the answers makes much more sense. Point taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. You can use the flair in conjunction with a link to his profile:

[image: profile for OpherV on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Or just a link with the user's name:

[**opherv**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/218107/opherv/)

See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/218107/opherv/flair for more examples.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's back to good 'ol links then :)

Comment: While the flair is neat, please **don't** put this in answers, since it is just noise in the context of answering questions. Referring to original authors by name and linking to the answers should be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

There is no shortcut for this. Not only would I say that there is no need for a shortcut, but I'd go as far as saying you probably shouldn't be linking to a user page anyway.

The user page has some basic bio information (if provided), a list of questions and answers posted by the user, and a few other sections relating to the user's activity on the site and across the network. I highly doubt this information would be relevant to your answer (except in rare cases on a meta site, which isn't significant enough to warrant a shortcut).

What you should be doing instead is linking to *the answer* rather than *the user*. You are, after all, referring to the answer from your own answer. That answer is where the relevant information is. When you refer to an source and provide a link, it should go to that source (the answer), not a place where you can dig around and look for the source yourself (the user page).

**Summary:** No, and linking to a user page from an answer is not very useful.

Comment: What if you want to give credit for a helpful comment? Linking to the comment itself is not a good option. Once I get an interesting feedback in a comment, it's best to make it part of my post, and delete the comment.